# The equality of LIKE '%$word%' in JavaScript RegExp AKA How to make a JavaScript search engine

Tags: javascript, regex, arrays, search-engine

I have a localStorage object that contains JSON data that yes, I have already parsed.

Within that data, I wish to search an array for something, such as "ANYTHING HERE "+keyword+"ANYTHING HERE"; Like an SQL "LIKE ''" query.

---

Ahh yes, indexOf seems to work fine for it. All I have to do now is just make a simple RegExp to validate the search input (only for length and characters--nothing fancy.)

You see, I am working on a local application that Google Chrome users will be able to set as their homepage, and hopefully, I can come up with some cool never-before-seen features.

Comment: This question basically evaluates to: Please write this regex for me. People are very happy to *help* you figure out why your own attempts haven't worked, but it's down to you to do the bulk of the work. So the first thing to do is read up on regular expressions and give it a go. [MDC's page on them](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) is pretty good.

Comment: Please clean up your `"`s and `'`s. I can't tell what is code and what isn't.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know if one string appears within another you might want to use the [indexOf method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).

```
if(jsonstring.indexOf(keyword) != -1){
    console.log("keyword appears in jsonstring");
}
```

Comment: Ahh yes. I totally forgot about the indexOf() method.
Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

May be this if you are using javascript

```
pattern = /keyword/g
for(i=0;i<jsonobj.length;i++){
    if(pattern.test(jsonobj[i])){
        // it matches the element that has the text 'keyword' in it
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex pattern `/\w*X\w*/gi`

Example: Find any like OR, AND to replace uppercase.

`g: Global`
`i: insensitive`
`m: multi-line`

```js
let _like = "examPle OrTeeeeest tOst iAnDi liKe oRNot MK7".replace(/\w*AND\w*|\w*OR\w*/gi, 
  function (x) {
    return x.toUpperCase();
  });
console.log(_like);
```